# Object throws itself across screen for no reason

Tags: animation, physics

I can't seem to get a simple cube to topple this single domino.

The domino is an active rigid body that is stood upright in frame 1. The cube is an active rigid body set to animated. The cube doesn't even move as I haven't set any keyframes, but the moment I push play on the timeline the domino hurls itself across the screen like it's been hit by a bullet!

Even when I set keyframes on the cube and have it move forward it makes no difference. Before it even makes contact with the domino the thing hurls itself across the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe apply the scale of both your objects, or please share your file

Comment: Please indicate via Blender screen captures and words, which of the following best describes the domino ... The domino sits on top of the plane ... the domino intersects the plane.  Please show all, or the absence  of, keyframes on your objects.

Comment: I hadn't applied the scale. I tried now and the domino flies directly into the air.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the images above. Image 3 shows no keyframes on the small cube that I'm trying to animate.  Image 2 shows the domino intersecting the plane slightly. It refuses to sit on the plane because as soon as the animation starts it drops down slightly. I have applied the scale to all objects now. This has made it worse. The domino now leaps into the air and dances around the plane.